# Tiling <div> elements without mosaic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I like using mosaic because when a user increases the size of their browser, it will automatically move around to find the best possible fit. 5 columns can resize to four columns quite nicely. I'd like an effect similar to this, but without the "move to find best fit".

Right now I'm using a table to store some data, each cell of size 300x250. The problem arises when a user increases the size of the page, since cells are rigid and will not reduce column size to compensate, and I end up with cells outside the width of the page, necessitating scrolling.

How can I achieve this effect? To summarize:

- start with for example 5 columns that span the width of the page
- if the user zooms in to the point where an element would go beyond the width of a page, make it into four columns instead
- if the user zooms out, have it go back to five columns (but cap it at five)

Is there an easy method to get this tiling scheme? Here's an image to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how [`display: inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#value-def-inline-block) elements are laid out. Combine with `min-width` if you want them to be uniform rather than dictated by their actual content.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/sosudoqi/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      min-width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that some old versions of IE don't like you to take an element (like `div`) that defaults to `display: block` and make it `inline-block` instead. If you need to support them, use an element (like `span`) that defaults to `inline-block` instead.